# Associate a value with a subclass in c#

Tags: c#, components

I have the following class and my question lies with it's GetComponent function

```
class GameObject
{ 

    private List<GameComponent> _components = new List<GameComponent>();
    public void AddComponent(GameComponent component)
    void RemoveComponent(string name)
    public T GetComponent<T>(string name) where T : GameComponent

}

class GameComponent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So in GetComponent i want to get the component identified by `name` and return it as T.

So i would call
`NavigationComponent navigation = gameObject.GetComponent<NavigationComponent>("navigation");`
where NavigationComponent would be a subclass of GameComponent

Since each NavigationComponent instance is only ever going to have the same name, "navigation", i am pondering if i can do something to simplify the GetComponent to the following

`NavigationComponent navigation = gameObject.GetComponent<NavigationComponent>();`

Thanks in advance.

Update 1

Well i should mention that the GameObject works like a set of GameObjects, identified by their name, so there can be only one of each in it.

So to elaborate lets say we have
`class SimpleNavigation : GameComponent {...}`
`class AdvancedNavigation : GameComponent {...}`
`class SensorSystem : GameComponent {...}`

Then i would give SimpleNavigation and AdvancedNavigation the Name "navigation" and to the SensorSystem the name "sensor"

So i cannot have both SimpleNavigation and AdvancedNavigation in the above example.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I fear that i might be placing too many constrains when there isn't much to gain and longterm the specifications might change, but that is outside of the scope of the question i guess

Comment: Have you heard of Dependency Injection (IoC: Inversion of Control) ?

Comment: So you want to get the `NavigationComponent` from a List of `GameComponent`?

Comment: No i haven't, i will go look it up now

Comment: @GenericTypeTea yes that would be correct

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: @GenericTypeTea I am using .net 3.5, i am working with XNA and i don't think i can use it with c# 4.0 if you are thinking about something that new.

Comment: Why are you using the "name" parameter? It looks like the name parameter is just a mapping to the Type of component you want, which is already captured in your T generic parameter. You could just use the type of T to control your logic.

Comment: I have updated my question since it didn't reflect well on what i was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten:

You've mentioned that `.Name` *should* remain as a property on your `GameComponent` class--so one option to consider is overriding the equality operator to say "if two instances of `GameComponent` have the same name then they should be considered equal".  Combined with [Dave's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319960/associate-a-value-with-a-subclass-in-c/3320075#3320075) of using `OfType()` you would have something like this:

```
class GameObject
{ 

  private List<GameComponent> _components = new List<GameComponent>();

  public T GetComponent<T>(string name) where T : GameComponent, new
  {
    return
      (from c in _components.OfType<T>()
      where c == new T { Name = name }
      select c).FirstOrDefault();
  }
} 

class GameComponent
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public bool Equals(GameComponent other)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
      return true;
    }
    return Equals(other.Name, Name);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
    {
      return false;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
    {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj.GetType() != typeof(GameComponent))
    {
      return false;
    }
    return Equals((GameComponent)obj);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
  }
}
```

It's worth thinking through whether or not you want to implement this approach--it will affect any equality-checks (not reference-checks).  However it's a very powerful ability to say "X and Y should be considered equal when X"--and equality overloading lets you implement that logic in a single centralized home (right on the entity).

Comment: I have already implemented the methods above, the GetComponent with FirstOrDefault and a lamda, but i thought i wasn't needed to show it since i actually wanted to change it. On the first note, because i want to have GameObjects that might have a NavigationComponent and a SensesComponent etc. On the second note, to avoid casting it from where i call it, less lines of code where i want to call it.

Comment: ahh, I didn't understand the intent of your question.  I've updated my answer with another approach to consider--it might not be what you need in *this* case, but it's worth considering

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if all NavigationComponents will have the same name, how will you distinguish between them?  If you only want to return a single NavigationComponent, you will need a unique identifier.

You can use the OfType() method to return all instances of a type:

`var navigationComponents = _components.OfType<NavigationComponent>();`

From there, you can select a single NavigationComponent by some unique identifier:

`NavigationComponent nc = navigationComponents.Where(n => n.Id == 1);`

Comment: Ah very nice, that seems to be what i am looking for. Well so far i can think of only needing one component of each type, but not all GameObjects have the same set of components, one might have a Navigation and a Sensor, one might have only a Sensor etc.

Comment: Your answer made me think a little bit better about what i wanted to achieve, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: In response to your edit:

> Then i would give SimpleNavigation and
>   AdvancedNavigation the Name
>   "navigation" and to the SensorSystem
>   the name "sensor"

If this is the case, then you really can't hope to have an interface like this...

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : GameComponent { }
```

...because multiple `GameComponent` object types may potentially share the same name. So you cannot infer name from type.

Why not go with an `enum` instead? Then you might have something like this:

```
public enum ComponentType
{
    Navigation,
    Sensor // etc.
}
```

And your `GameObject` class could in turn hold a `Dictionary<ComponentType, GameComponent>`.

*Then* your `GetComponent` method could look like this:

```
GameComponent GetComponent(ComponentType type) { }
```

Anyway, it's a thought...

---

I think what makes more sense is this:

Firstly, if you're looking up by name, use a `Dictionary<string, GameComponent>` instead of a `List<GameComponent>`. This will give you O(1) lookup time instead of O(N).

Now, if you want name to be dependent on type, define your `GameComponent` class like this:

```
class GameComponent
{
    public virtual string Name
    {
        // You could also hard-code this or cache it
        // for better performance.
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}
```

You might then choose to override the `Name` property in your derived methods, like so:

```
class NavigationComponent : GameComponent
{
    public override string Name
    {
        // This returns the same thing as GetType().Name,
        // but it's faster.
        get { return "NavigationComponent"; }
    }
}
```

Then your `AddComponent` method would be:

```
public void AddComponent(GameComponent component)
{
    _components.Add(component.Name, component);
}
```

and your `GetComponent` method would be simple:

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : GameComponent
{
    return _components[typeof(T).Name] as T;
}
```

Comment: I havent typed in your code yet, but how can i call .Name on the type if it isn't static?

Comment: @Xtapodi: Calling `this.GetType().Name` will return the name of the object's *type* (itself a `System.Type` object). This would normally not make sense, except that you've specified you actually want the name of a `GameComponent` object to be the same as the name of its type. So for this reason, the [`Type.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) property is precisely what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your new update. If something like virtual static methods was possible then i suppose i could do it, i hoped that some solution might exist with attributes, which it might, but i guess it will be rather expensive performance wise to put in there and i wouldn't be able to enforce it anyway. But i have never used attributes so i might be wrong. Could i enforce that GameObject subclasses have a [ComponentType(string name)] attribute?